# Adding virtual users to postfix without modifying main config files?

Tags: postfix, configuration

In other services (e.g. httpd, supervisor, yum, etc), it's possible to add to the configuration without modifying the main configuration files (by placing files in, e.g. `/etc/httpd/conf.d`, `/etc/supervisor/conf.d`, `yum.repos.d`, etc).

I'm wondering if a similar setup is possible for postfix.

I have a setup script for a mostly-self-contained webapp that includes the need to set up a virtual mailbox. I'd rather not fiddle directly with the primary postfix files. Instead, I'd much prefer to just add files that postfix then reads in for configuration.

However, I can't find anything that discusses this, and it appears that the built-in configuration expects all configuration to exist in the same directory.

I understand if I was able to get this to work, I guess I'd still need to run postmap on the additional files to convert them into .db files. That's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, **all** configuration parameters defined for postfix (see [man 5 postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html)) should be placed in one and only one file, `$etcdir/postfix/main.cf`. So postfix doesn't have some kind of `Include this file/directory` in its configuration syntax like other software such as apache httpd, sudo and the others.

Fortunately, you can always use external source for [some parameters](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_mailbox) like list of virtual domain, list of virtual user or where is location user mailbox. In fact, it unusual to hard-coded this configuration in `main.cf`. The common practice is outsourcing this kind of information to [table that postfix support](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types), such as hash file, SQL Table or LDAP.

Example configuration in `main.cf`

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/vdomain
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
...another configuration...
```